# Biased Clipper Circuit

Tags: diodes

I was studying for my end-term exam through past year papers(of my college).
I came across this question in which a diode is in series with an AC voltage source and a DC voltage source.

Info given:

- VB = DC Source
- Vin = AC Source
- Consider diode forward voltage drop is 0.7 V (Si)

**I am not sure if this is indeed a biased clipper.**

I was only taught simple biased clipper but I tried Googling and found out that this is a Biased Series Clipper--it is the exact opposite of usual examples...

### My attempt

Since D1 is reverse biased, it becomes an open circuit for positive input waveform--that means the **max Vout in the positive cycle is 0 Volts.**

*Am I correct?*

Edit: Somebody has posted the exact question on [Chegg](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/q2-given-circuit-maximum-value-vout-positive-cycle-input-voltage-consider-diode-forward-vo-q78918635)--sadly I don't have an account on Chegg.

Comment: Diode becomes forward biased during positive cycle when \$V_{in}\ge V_{B} + V_{D1 fwd}\$. Where \$V_{D1 fwd}\$ is the diode threshold voltage for conduction. With this info, can you solve the question?

Comment: 5 is greater than 2.7--so this would mean a forward bias irrespective of the DC source? In that case, KVL gives Vout = 7.7 Volts... Would that be correct @AJN ?

Comment: To use KVL, you must first draw a diagram with reference directions clearly marked. Please update the circuit diagram. Otherwise, there could be confusion, as to whether, voltages add or subtract.

Comment: Yeah sorry @AJN. I could just use Vin - Vout = 2.7 (Is their a name for this "law"?) Thanks once again for telling that it would be forward biased. Vout = 2.3 V ,right?

Comment: You are right that, It *is* KVL. I intended my comment to mean that a diagram is needed to check if the add/subtract operations of KVL are correct/consistent.

Comment: Actually, it is just an application of KVL + you are correct about being careful with the signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the following:

- \$V_2\$ is always \$V_{out} + V_B\$
- because of the diode current in the circuit can only flow in one direction
- therefore there are two cases:

1. no current flows and \$V_{out}\$ is zero
2. current flows in the circuit, \$V_{out}\$ is positive and \$V_2 = V_{in} - 0.7\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9WatP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the second case \$V_{out} = V_{in} - 0.7 - V_B\$ and the condition \$V_{out} > 0\$ means we must have \$V_{in} > 0.7 + V_B\$.

If \$V_{in} < 0.7 + V_B\$ then we are in the first case and \$V_{out} = 0\$.

Comment: So, Max Vout = 2.3 V? I think I do understand it now after combining your and @AJN's post. Btw what is the law that gives Vin-Vout=2.7 called?(I know I got the wrong result by calling it KVL in my comment above--can't apply KVL on a wire) THANKS ONCE AGAIN!(Can't upvote due to low reputation)

Comment: Yes, the max for Vout is 5-0.7-2 = 2.3. Not sure about the name of that law.